# How Can we split message which will be sent by push notification Server Into Two Lines?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have created local notification and initially I didn't get a banner for the notification. Then I used a third party library called `TWMessage`.

In the banner I am not able to see more lines of the message. So can any one suggest how to get multiple lines of data?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
First line \\n
Second Line
```

instead of

```
First line \n
Second Line
```